# Why is my console.log statement running 9 times when the page loads and gives me 0 every time?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am working on a tic-tac-toe game and i am trying to send an alert when player one has 5 X's on the board resulting in a tie.

Basically player one always goes first and starts with X and if player one's counter hits 5, i want to send an alert. But whenever i console.log p1Counter, i get 0 9 times when the page loads before i even start to play.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id='heading'>Tic-Tac-Toe World Championship 2021</h1>
    <div id='game-board'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id=button-box>
      <button type='button'>Reset!</button>
    </div>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

  let boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

  let p1Counter = 0;
  let p2Counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    console.log(p1Counter)

    if (p1Counter === 5) {
      window.alert('Tie Game...')
    }

    boxes[i].onclick = elem => {

    if ((elem.target.textContent === 'X') ||
        (elem.target.textContent === 'O')) {
      return;
    }

    if (p1Counter === p2Counter) {
      elem.target.textContent = 'X';
      p1Counter++;
    } else {
      elem.target.textContent = 'O';
      p2Counter++;
    }
   }
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: You're making a loop for all the `td` in your table, since you have 9 it will always run 9 times the console log

Comment: What do you think `for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)` does?

Comment: @PietroNadalini The game is working fine so the counters must be incrementing properly, i am wondering why it isnt giving me the updated counter results

Comment: @Barmar it iterates over all of the boxes (td's) right?

Comment: Right. And while it's iterating, you do `console.log(p1Counter)`, so you get 9 logs.

Answer (score 0):

Because after `onclick` assign, it return to new loop and never increase your variable.

```
boxes[i].onclick = elem => {}
```

The `p1Counter` only increase when you click to the td tag, I add some style to display the box to easy to view.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id='heading'>Tic-Tac-Toe World Championship 2021</h1>
    <div id='game-board'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id=button-box>
      <button type='button'>Reset!</button>
    </div>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

  let boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

  let p1Counter = 0;
  let p2Counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    console.log(p1Counter);
    
    if (p1Counter === 5) {
      window.alert('Tie Game...')
    }

    boxes[i].onclick = elem => {

    if ((elem.target.textContent === 'X') ||
        (elem.target.textContent === 'O')) {
      return;
    }

    if (p1Counter === p2Counter) {
      elem.target.textContent = 'X';
      p1Counter++;
      console.log(p1Counter);
    } else {
      elem.target.textContent = 'O';
      p2Counter++;
      console.log(p2Counter);
    }
   }
  }
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop only runs 1 time, when your page loads, then the only code that gets run again is the part inside the `p1Counter` and `p2Counter` get updated.

And your `console.log` gets run 9 times due to your loops that gets 9 `td` elements.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

  let boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

  let p1Counter = 0;
  let p2Counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].onclick = elem => {
      if (p1Counter === 5) {
        window.alert('Tie Game...')
      }
      if ((elem.target.textContent === 'X') ||
        (elem.target.textContent === 'O')) {
        return;
      }

      if (p1Counter === p2Counter) {
        elem.target.textContent = 'X';
        p1Counter++;
      } else {
        elem.target.textContent = 'O';
        p2Counter++;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id='heading'>Tic-Tac-Toe World Championship 2021</h1>
  <div id='game-board'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id=button-box>
    <button type='button'>Reset!</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```